# Get Information About a Website Using there URL in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, url, webkit

Im trying to Get Information About a Website like title (Like what you see in safari in  the Tabs and Windows)and Description of that Website from its URL Without Using the WebKit Framework in Xcode and Displaying it on screen as text. I Just want to know have to obtain the title of the Website/Page that the URL Belongs to using Cocoa. Is There a Tutorial or Something. It will be a Big Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.title"];
    navbar.title = title;
}
```

Taken from: http://blog.mcohen.me/2008/12/12/getting-the-title-of-a-web-view-in-cocoa-touch/

If you don't want to display the webview, make it hidden and use above delegate method to get what you want...

Answer (score 0):

A way you could do it is by downloading the HTML content at the target url and parse it, for example using [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple).

Example (not tested):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];

//Only using this for simplicity of the example.
//You should really use an asynchronous method instead (see `NSURLSession`).
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Parse HTML and search for title element
TFHpple *hppleParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
TFHppleElement *titleElement = [hppleParser search:@"//title"][0];

NSString titleString = titleElement.text;
```